# Why wont my Ps4 controller work once I play a movie?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4, controllers

Just the other day I took apart my controller to clean one of the keys (it was starting to stick) after reassembling it I made sure all the keys worked properly and played a game for a min before shutting down. Now today I was going to watch a movie and after selecting the disk icon I couldn't press play, couldn't cycle through the movie title options, but I can still turn off the controller or go to ps4 main menu where those same buttons would then work. I tried another controlled and it worked perfectly fine and was able to play the movie but what's up with my other controller.

TLDR Buttons X, O, Dpad, & Toggles, Start not responding under movie screen on ps4.

Comment: How extensivly have you tested the reassembled controller? 1 minute of playing doesn't seem very extensive

Comment: Not at all I did enough to test out all the buttons then put the playstation to sleep

Comment: Does the buttons work on a game?